# Angular abstract factory

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I have the following service definition. It's looking like I'm going to have to repeat this code for every entity I want to expose which is pretty ugly. I'm not marvellous with Javascript so I can't really figure out a way to create a template service generating factory where I can just supply the name DeltaRunAuditService and then lowercase it and remove the 'Service' to provide the url? Any ideas

Thanks,
Mark,

```
app.service('DeltaRunAuditService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function getDeltaRunAudits(pageNumber, size) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber > 0 ? pageNumber - 1 : 0;
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/deltarunaudit?page=' + pageNumber + '&size=' + size
        });
    }

    return {
        getDeltaRunAudits: getDeltaRunAudits
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ['DeltaRunAudit', 'User'].forEach(function(entity){
          var serviceName = entity + 'Service';
          var url = entity.toLowerCase();
          app.service(serviceName, ['$http', function ($http) {

            function get(pageNumber, size) {
                pageNumber = pageNumber > 0 ? pageNumber - 1 : 0;
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'api/' + url + '?page=' + pageNumber + '&size=' + size
                });
            }

            return {
                get: get
            };

          }]);
    })
```

If you really want to do create service for all of your entities since your service name is like `'getDeltaRunAuditsService'` you can just use `'get'` or `'getAll'` naming in your methods